# Javascript / EJS Code showing error : TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'name')

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

The code does run at first but the moment I submit my first post request, it gives the following error :

node:events:504
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'name')

Currently using : Node.js, mongoose

Packages used : express, bodyParser, ejs, Mongoose

JS file code :

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
app.use(express.static("public"));

const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

const ejs = require("ejs");
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/learndb");


const questionSchema =
{
  question : String,
  answer : String
};

const Question = mongoose.model("Question", questionSchema);

const subjectSchema =
{
  name : String,
  questions : [questionSchema]
};

const Subject = mongoose.model("Subject", subjectSchema);

app.post("/", function(req, res)
{
  const subjectName=  req.body.subjectName;

  const subject = new Subject({ name: subjectName});
  subject.save();
  res.redirect("/");

});


app.get("/", function(req, res)
{
  Subject.find({}, function(err, foundSubjects)
  {
    res.render("home", {whichSubjects: foundSubjects});
  });

});
```

HTML/EJS File code:

```
<body>
          <h1>Choose a Subject</h1>

            <% whichSubjects.forEach(function(eachSubject) { %>
              <div class="">
                <form class="" action="/<%=eachSubject.name%>" method="get">
                        <button type="submit" name="button">  <%=eachSubject.name%></button>
                </form>
              </div>
            <% }) %>

          <div class="">
          <form class="" action="/" method="post">
                <input type="text" name="subjectName" value="">
                <button type="submit" name="button">Add A Subject</button>
          </form>
          </div>

  </body>
```

Comment: The `save()` method returns a promise. Make sure the promise is resolved before redirecting. Look into using `await` for example `await subject.save()` should do the trick

Comment: Hello! I tried what you said and it is giving me the error.
SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules

Comment: Make your route an async one.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was so simple but we missed it. The first thing wrong in your code are the paths. You have two paths named `/`. You want to make your home route the place your visualize all the data and then make a form that posts the data to a different route and upon success, should redirect to your home route. In your case all you have to do is change the post route on the hmtl to `/addsubject` and on the js file to `app.post('/addsubject' rest of code`

```js
//Generate express app
const express = require('express');                     
const app = express();

app.set('views', './views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
//Generate body parser
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');  
app.use(bodyParser.json());     
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

//Connect to MongoDB
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/learndb');


const subJectSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:  String,
    questions: [{type: String}]
})

const Subject = mongoose.model('Subject', subJectSchema);



app.post('/addsubject', (req, res) => {
    const  subjectName  = req.body.subjectName;

    const subject = new Subject({ name: subjectName });
    subject.save((err, subject) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log("User Saved");
        }
    });
    res.redirect('/');
});


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    Subject.find({}, (err, subjects) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.render('home', { subjectList: subjects });
        }
    });
});


app.listen(4000, () => {
    console.log('Server started on port 3000');
});
```

```html
<body>
    <h1>Choose Subject</h1>

    <div>
        <form action="/addsubject" method="post">

            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="subjectName" id="name">
            <input type="submit" value="Create Subject">
        </form>
    </div>
    <% if(subjectList.length> 0){ %>
        <% subjectList.forEach(subject=>{ %>
            <p>
                <%= subject.name %>
            </p>
        <% }) %>
 <% } else { %>
<p>No subjects found Add Some</p>
 <% } %>

</body>
```

Comment: Again receiving a new error : SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: Try now just updated the syntax

Comment: Although the code worked, the initial error hasn't. The error that I'm receiving is still the same.

Comment: When you `console.log(subjectName)`, what do you get? are you using `body-parser`? it might be a node node process issue

Comment: Yes I am using Bodyparser. After which line do you want me to console log the subjectName?

Comment: I'm suspecting it might be a node process issue console log `subJectName` before `await subject.save()`. if that fails, first enter `lsof -i :3000` to see if you have any processes runing. if you see a process and on a unix/linux machine, run `killall -9 node` then restart your node server. Make sure to close all processes running on your terminals.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243709/discussion-between-sebastian-gbudje-and-nsack).

Comment: where exactly do you want me to type lsof -i :3000
On the hyper terminal? It is giving me the error. "bash: lsof: command not found"
On my hyper terminal, only two processes are running along with my app.js i.e mongod and mongo